# Change multiple dataframes in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have, for example, this three datasets (in my case, they are many more and with a lot of variables):

```
data_frame1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,5,3,3,2), b=c(3,6,1,5,5), c=c(4,4,1,9,2))
data_frame2 <- data.frame(a=c(6,0,9,1,2), b=c(2,7,2,2,1), c=c(8,4,1,9,2))
data_frame2 <- data.frame(a=c(0,0,1,5,1), b=c(4,1,9,2,3), c=c(2,9,7,1,1))
```

on each data frame I want to add a variable resulting from a transformation of an existing variable on that data frame. I would to do this by a loop. For example:

```
datasets <- c("data_frame1","data_frame2","data_frame3")
vars <- c("a","b","c")
for (i in datasets){
    for (j in vars){
        # here I need a code that create a new variable with transformed values
        # I thought this would work, but it didn't...
        get(i)$new_var <- log(get(i)[,j])
    }
}
```

Do you have some valid suggestions about that?

Moreover, it would be great for me if it were possible also to assign the new column names (in this case `new_var`) by a character string, so I could create the new variables by another for loop nested in the other two.

Hope I've not been too tangled in explain my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks. Could you also explain me the other method?

Comment: I had read your deleted comment. You sayd that there is a less complicated method to do this.

Comment: No, a log for some columns, and other transformations for other columns...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put your dataframes in a list and use `lapply` to process them one by one. So no need to use a loop in this case.

For example you can do this :

```
data_frame1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,5,3,3,2), b=c(3,6,1,5,5), c=c(4,4,1,9,2))
data_frame2 <- data.frame(a=c(6,0,9,1,2), b=c(2,7,2,2,1), c=c(8,4,1,9,2))
data_frame3 <- data.frame(a=c(0,0,1,5,1), b=c(4,1,9,2,3), c=c(2,9,7,1,1))

ll <- list(data_frame1,data_frame2,data_frame3)
lapply(ll,function(df){
  df$log_a <- log(df$a)          ## new column with the log a
  df$tans_col <- df$a+df$b+df$c  ## new column with sums of some columns or any other           
                                 ##   transformation
  ###  .....
  df

})
```

the dataframe1 becomes :

```
[[1]]
  a b c     log_a tans_col
1 1 3 4 0.0000000        8
2 5 6 4 1.6094379       15
3 3 1 1 1.0986123        5
4 3 5 9 1.0986123       17
5 2 5 2 0.6931472        9
```

Comment: @agstudy I tried your solution on my data. I notice that it doesn't really write the new variables. In you example, log_a and tans_col are not inserted in the data frames. Certainly I'm mistakiing something...

Comment: @this.is.not.a.nick in this case I use the `$` will create the new variable.. df$log_a will create a variable of name log_a...what have you tried with your data?

Comment: @agstudy Yes, but if, following your example, I then type `ll[[1]]$log_a`, R returns me `NULL`

Comment: @this.is.not.a.nick it is normal , R do the transformation in a copy of ll so you need to do something like `ll <- lapply(ll,function(df)...` to change the value of your list..

Comment: ...as I imagined, my problem was stupid. :) Thanks a lot @agstudy

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need and wanted to change also the columns in my actual list of dataframes.

I found a great method [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/simplest-way-to-modify-the-same-column-in-multiple-dataframes-in-a-list/13076) (the `purrr::map2` method in the question works for dataframes with different columns), followed by

```
list2env(list_of_dataframes ,.GlobalEnv)
```