# Reflecting changes in a dataframe by Modifying a list containing the dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list containing a couple of data frames. I'm applying lapply on the list and directing output to the same list itself. I expected that this would change the dataframes themselves, but it doesn't. Can someone help with this? I guess it should be quite straight forward, but can't find anything that helps.

Thanks.

Sample data: (Source: [Change multiple dataframes in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429686/change-multiple-dataframes-in-a-loop))

```
data_frame1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,5,3,3,2), b=c(3,6,1,5,5), c=c(4,4,1,9,2))
data_frame2 <- data.frame(a=c(6,0,9,1,2), b=c(2,7,2,2,1), c=c(8,4,1,9,2))
data_frame3 <- data.frame(a=c(0,0,1,5,1), b=c(4,1,9,2,3), c=c(2,9,7,1,1))

ll <- list(data_frame1,data_frame2,data_frame3)
ll <- lapply(ll,function(df){
df$log_a <- log(df$a)          ## new column with the log a
  df$tans_col <- df$a+df$b+df$c  ## new column with sums of some columns or any other           
  df
})
```

Results:

```
ll
[[1]]
  a b c     log_a tans_col
1 1 3 4 0.0000000        8
2 5 6 4 1.6094379       15
3 3 1 1 1.0986123        5
4 3 5 9 1.0986123       17
5 2 5 2 0.6931472        9

[[2]]
  a b c     log_a tans_col
1 6 2 8 1.7917595       16
2 0 7 4      -Inf       11
3 9 2 1 2.1972246       12
4 1 2 9 0.0000000       12
5 2 1 2 0.6931472        5

[[3]]
  a b c    log_a tans_col
1 0 4 2     -Inf        6
2 0 1 9     -Inf       10
3 1 9 7 0.000000       17
4 5 2 1 1.609438        8
5 1 3 1 0.000000        5





data_frame1
  a b c
1 1 3 4
2 5 6 4
3 3 1 1
4 3 5 9
5 2 5 2
```

Comment: Why on earth would you expect it would change the data frames themselves?

Comment: R objects are typically (almost always) passed / copied by value, not by reference. If this is the behavior you are looking for, look into the `R.oo`, `proto`, `data.table` or `ref` packages, for example.

Comment: I apologize if it is supposed to be common knowledge. Found a work-around though. In hindsight, I don't understand now why I expected it to be passed by reference in first place.